# NET CORE 6 - How to add additional attributes to the Validation Summary?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Is it possible to add the “data-valmsg-for” to the Validation Summary using a tag helper?

Something like...

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "asp-validation-summary")]
public class ValidationSummaryTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public class MyValidationTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {       
            output.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-for", "DOB");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: `ModelState.AddModelError()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Do you want to display `data-valmsg-for="DOB"` in `<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>`. The code you updated in your question does, but you need to remove the built-in TagHelper first.

In _ViewImports.cshtml, add `@removeTagHelper`:

```
@using ProjectName
@using ProjectName.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ValidationSummaryTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, ProjectName
```

Test Result:

[image]

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Perhaps you have misunderstood ASP.NET Core's model validation. It outputs the corresponding html code to display the validation message through the specific command encapsulated inside.

For example, I have a test model, where the `Email` field is required:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then the validation code about Email in my form could be like this:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
Email:  <input asp-for="Email" /> <br />
<span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
```

You can see the generated code in your browser like this:

[image]

When an error in our model validation framework occurs, the jQuery places the error message to the body of the span:

[image]

Therefore, the `<li data-valmsg-for="DOB">You must enter your date birth</li>` you mentioned may not be able to complete the corresponding validation.

You can refer to the generated Html code and add your custom information in the `Input`, like this:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
Email:  <input asp-for="Email" data-val-required="You must enter your email" /> <br />
<span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
```

Test Result:

[image]

For more details about the validation tag helpers, you can refer to this document: [The Validation Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-validation-tag-helpers).

Comment: How do you extend the validation-summary by using tag helpers?

Comment: Hi @Joe Black, I updated the answer, you can check if this is what you want.